# How to sum values from a database column in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

as a newbie I want to sum the values of a column `pv` from a database table `evm` in my model and store it in a `variable`. I have tried the SQL code `SELECT SUM(pv) FROM evm;` but that doesn't seem to work.I would be grateful if you lend me an aid regarding how to pull this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a native query and get the response in the resultset to populate the field of your pojo. Once you have the POJO/DTO created as the list of result set perform your sum on the field by Iterating the list.

Comment: you mean I should store them in a collection(ArrayList)? how do we sum the items in a collection then?

Comment: No but something like this :- 

 String sql="Select Sum(Price) as sumprice from sold";
                          pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                          rs=pst.executeQuery();
                          if(rs.next()){
                              String sum = rs.getString("sumprice");
                              textField_2.setText(sum);

Comment: can we do this with java? since I'm not good with SQL to be honest.

Comment: What is your persistence layer on ie JDBC, JPA over Hibernate, Eclipse link etc ? Please provide some more pointers. If you want to do this dirty way then (assuming your are using JDBC) file the query, load the POJO create the list and perform your sum on the field by Iterating the list.

Comment: This is AnyLogic (a simulation tool); you don't normally use 'raw' Java DB query syntax since AnyLogic provides various wrapper/helper methods (and there is no explicit persistence layer --- AnyLogic simulations have a built-in HSQLDB database that you query).

Answer (score 0):

You do just use the SQL you have suggested. (The database in an AnyLogic model is a standard HSQLDB database which supports this SQL syntax.)

The simplest way to execute it is to use AnyLogic's in-built functions for such queries (as would be produced by the **Insert Database Query** wizard), so

```
mySumVariable = selectFirstValue("SELECT SUM(pv) FROM evm;");
```

You didn't say what errors you had; obviously the table and column has to exist (and the column you're summing needs to be numeric, though NULLs are OK), as does the variable you're assigning the sum to.

If you wanted to do this in a way which more easily fits one of the standard query 'forms' suggested by the wizard (i.e., not having to know particular SQL syntax) you could just adapt the "Iterate over returned rows and do something" code to 'explicitly' sum the columns; e.g., (using the Query DSL format this time):

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(evm).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    mySumVariable += row.get(evm.pv);
}
```